# What causes sleep inertia?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, brain, sleep

Sometimes after a nap, I wake up in a state of grogginess. I learned that this is actually called [sleep inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_inertia). I'm able to find lots of methods to *overcome* this, but what causes it in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to states of brain activation promoted by the **reticular formation**, specifically with the **ascending reticular activating system** that mediates the general activation of the upper areas, for sleep these areas should promote states of relative low activity promoting the cerebral activation profiles during sleep, it is also interesting to study the **descending reticular activating system** that mediates the general muscular activation that is generally inhibited during sleep (except clinical problems among others) (that is why you can not make muscular efforts when waking up, try an experiment: try to clench your fists strongly when you are awakening).

Comment: Try adding some sources to your points. It would help and form a much better answer.